# How to allow contributor users to add web parts

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, administration

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, currently contributor users with the following permission level, cannot add web parts:-

[image]

I think that assigning them a Design permission will solve this issue, but at the same time they will be able to modify the site collection, which I do not want to grant.so can anyone advice what is the best approach I can follow to allow contributor users to add web parts without being able to have Design permission level?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own permission set, where you should set and assign to the users:

**Site Permissions** :

Add and Customize Pages

Browse Directories

**Personal Permissions**

Add/Remove Personal Web Parts

Update Personal Web Parts

Comment: thanks for the reply, so i can edit the current contributor permission level and assign these permissions ? or i need to create a new permission level ?

Comment: but if i gave users "Add and Customize Pages" then they will be able to "edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor. ",, which i want to avoid... so in other words if i want users to add web parts then they will be able also to edit the web site using Microsoft SharePoint foundation-compatible editor ???

Comment: also why Add/Remove personal web parts permission is not enough to allow users to add web parts,, seems this is a bug in sharepoint !!! what do u think ?

Comment: You can do it either way, modify current permission level or create new permission level.

Comment: yes i know that, but if i want to allow users to add web parts , then i need to gran them the following permission "Add and Customize Pages" , and this permission will allow users to do extra functions i do not want them to do such as add site columns, delete site columns, change the site layout ,, which i do not want them to be able to do !!

Comment: so is there a way to modify the "Add and Customize Pages" permission itself ??

Comment: This may be by design as it is. You add hide specific links on the sharepoint UI using javascript or somethig.

Comment: No, there is no way to modify the "Add and Customize Pages" permission itself

Comment: So you think that hiding the Design link will not allow users to modify the design! and i want Designer users to see the Design link. so im this case i have to force my javaScript to check the user permission before hiding the link, which will lead me to another truble in sharepoint (i am 100% sure). really i can not understand how sharepoint works on certain areas,, i mean if users want to add web parts there should be a separate permission for this,,

Comment: or at-least if a user can add/edit wiki page then he should be able to add web parts .. but why adding web parts will allow users to modify the site columns or have extra permission on the site collection level...

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom permission.  Give the exact permissions you want to give.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: the problem is that if i want to grant users to be able to add web parts they will also be able to change the web site design. and they will be able to access site settings add site column, delete site columns, import design package, etc...

Comment: what i am trying to find is just to allow contributor users to add web parts beside their default permissions such as add pages, edit pages, etc... but seems that giving them "Add and Customize Pages" permission, will be too much, as they will be able to access site settings also !!!